# Can I require a minimum Go version when compiling an app?

Tags: go

I'd like to make sure people aren't using Go 1.12 or older when compiling my application; mainly because this:

```
return fmt.Errorf("foo: %w", err)
```

Will compile fine in Go 1.12, but won't actually behave as expected as it requires runtime changes in Go 1.13 or newer to pick up on that `%w`.

And even there are changes which introduce a compile error, such as binary literals or `_` in numeric literals, a nicer "you need Go 1.13 or newer"-message would be better and less confusing, as not everyone may be familiar with Go and know what to do with a syntax error (it seems some people still use rather old Go versions).

I added `go 1.13` to my `go.mod` file, but I can still compile it fine with older versions (and adding `go 1.16` and compiling with Go 1.15 also works).

Is there any way to require a minimum Go version when compiling an app to prevent runtime errors and display a friendly error message?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The easiest way I could figure out is adding a new file with `+build !go1.13`; since Go version build tags are added for all newer versions (Go 1.14 has `go1.14`, `go1.13`, `go1.12`, etc.) it will compile only for versions older than Go 1.13, and will be ignored for any newer versions:

```
// +build !go1.13

package main

func init() {
    "You need Go 1.13 or newer to compile this program"
}
```

This introduces a deliberate compile error, which results in a reasonably nice error message:

```
$ go install ./cmd/app
# zgo.at/app/cmd/app
cmd/app/old.go:8:2: "You need Go 1.13 or newer to compile this program" evaluated but not used
```

Comment: TIL; nice hack. You can also mention the minimum version in `go.mod`, but that won't prevent you from compiling with an older version.

Comment: Yeah, that doesn't actually do all that much @TehSphinX, although it does disables incompatible features in newer Go versions IIRC so you can't "accidentally" use them. But as far as I know, that's all it really does. I forgot to mention this, but I'll update the question to point out this doesn't work as one might expect.

Comment: Yes, it will just try to compile with the old version anyway and only output an error if compilation fails. Which it doesn't with your `fmt` example.